# Xamarin for Windows Installation

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'd like to install the Xamarin Studio on Windows so I searched on google and it led me here https://store.xamarin.com/account/my/subscription/downloads. I clicked the download and the setup begins. I clicked CONTINUE and 'yes' to allow changes to my computer. And after that, nothing happened. I waited for a few minutes and still, nothing happens. I went back to that link and repeated all the steps but again, it didn't work. Help me pls I really need the XS :(

Comment: You need to install VS.  XS is no longer supported.

Comment: @Jason and i was wondering why an existing Xamarin Studio installation stopped working on my PC, thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Kristine

The best way to have Xamarin is installing the VS, since the 2015 version you can have Xamarin inside VS. BTW, you don't need to pay (but you can if you want to) because there is Community version of VS.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows OS, you don't need to download Xamarin Studio for developing with Xamarin.
Use VS 2017 is better, you browse https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/ to download and install Visual Studio 2017 because it supports Xamarin now(https://blog.xamarin.com/better-apps-visual-studio-2017/)

After you started downloaded file, you will see some options that you can choose. You can choose Xamarin.
If you don't know which ones should be chosen, just choose all.

It works for me.